# Referencia a objeto no establecida c# checkbox

Tags: c#, checkbox

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Buenas no entiendo porque no para de salirme este error. Ayer mismo me funcionaba cerre la solucion compile de nuevo y no funciona, alguien me puede echar una mano?

Comment: A ver es simple el valor es nul.. Ahora ¿por que te llega null? ¿Te conectas a una BD y no tienes coneccion? has debuggeado?

Comment: Yo creo que no tiene nada que ver la BD  porque realmente lo que quiero es comprobar unos checkbox de la interfaz en wpf , simplemente quiero con un checkbox poner los demas checkbox a checked

Comment: he mencionado la BD por decir algo, depura tu codigo los nullpointer son faciles de detectar

Comment: No veo el orden de tu codigo, cuando llamas a MarcarTodosLosCheck y si estas entrando por otro constructor tambien.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primero debes ejecutarse el metodo InitializeComponent(), que crea todo los elementos de la vista, luego puedes usar los componentes.

```
public SeleccionHorario(List<CheckBox> cb)
{
   //Primero inicializar los componentes, luego llenar el resto.
   InitializeComponent();

  // cb.Add(......)
}
```

Otra posibilidad es que estes entrando por otro constructor, entonces cuando queres recorrer el List en el foreach el mismo esta null, porque nunca se cargo al haber entrado por el constructor sin parametros. En ese caso el error esta en el formulario anterior donde lo estas llamando porque usas el constructor sin parametros. Tambien estas trabajando mal con el parametro porque tu constructor recibe un List y ese list lo estas rellenando local, lo cual quien llama al Constructor deberia pasarla la informacion.

Comment: Efectivamente no necesitaba una llamada al constructor pasandole ningun parametro, he creado la lista como una propiedad de la clase seleccion horario y el error que me daba era que me creaba una lista de null, efectivamente por que el initializeComponent estaba despues de  todos los .add. Asi que me funciona a la perfeccion ahora , muchisisimas gracias.